# Multi line uitextview

Tags: iphone, xcode, multiline

I was hoping I can get some help with creating a username and password box similar to the one Yahoo uses on their iPhone app. It seems to have a separator in the single textview box. I'm still new to using Cocoa so I still have a lot to learn.

I have attached an image of the screenshot I took.

Thanks!

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/62b3m.jpg)

Comment: Hi @ElijahGaraz and welcome to StackOverflow, we are not here to make your work but to help you if you got into trouble. Most of us will make more effort to answer your question if you show what you have tried!

Comment: From the looks of it, that seems more like a UITableView with 2 rows. Probably those rows each hold a custom cell, which itself contains a single-line UITextView.

Answer (score 0):

The Yahoo screenshot shows what looks like a grouped UITableView with two cells.  The separator is the line between the cells, and each of the cells would contain a UITextView.

Comment: Thank you for the comment.@Mattias - I have tried other things but couldn't quite get it right. Like i said I am new to this so I'm am also learning in the process. And to the other guys who helped out thank you very much and I will try your suggestions and see if I can get it right.